# Экспорт сгенерированного xlsx-файла пользователю с сервера

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

Добрый день.
Мне нужно отправить пользователю сгенерированный файл экселевской таблицы. Сам файл генерируется в одном классе. Текст генерации такой:

```
public XLSResult ExportToXLS()
    {
        var results = data;

        using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            //создаю лист
            p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Export data");
            ExcelWorksheet ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            ws.Name = "Export data"; //даю ему имя

            int colIndex = 1;
            int rowIndex = 1;
            //заполняю заголовки
            foreach (var column in columns)
            {
                var cell = ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex];

                var fill = cell.Style.Fill;
                fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Gray);


                var border = cell.Style.Border;
                border.Bottom.Style =
                    border.Top.Style =
                    border.Left.Style =
                    border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;


                cell.Value = column.DisplayName;

                colIndex++;
            }

            rowIndex = 2;
            colIndex = 1;
            //заполняю таблицу
            foreach (var result in (IList<ResultView>)results)
            {
                foreach (var column in columns)
                {
                    var cell = ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex];                     
                        cell.Value = result.GetType().GetProperty(column.Name).GetValue(result, null);                      
                    colIndex++;
                    //Setting borders of cell
                    var border = cell.Style.Border;
                    border.Left.Style = border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                }
                // --->
            }

            //итоговый файл

            XLSResult resultXLS = new XLSResult()
            {
                FileName = "testExport.xlsx",
                MIMEType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
            };

            var memoryStream = p.GetAsByteArray();
            resultXLS.File = memoryStream;

            return resultXLS;
        }


    }
```

Как видите, на выходе создается экземпляр класса, содержащий название, тип и массив байтов, содержащий файл. Класс для подобного объекта объявлен в таком виде:

```
public class XLSResult : IPageXLSFileResult
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string MIMEType { get; set; }

    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

Затем в контроллере мы выполняем проверку и отдаем получаемый файл через File(fileBytes, fileType, fileName)

```
if (result is IPageXLSFileResult)
            {
                return File(((IPageXLSFileResult)result).File, ((IPageXLSFileResult)result).MIMEType,
                    ((IPageXLSFileResult)result).FileName);
            }
```

Затем с помощью ajax-запроса пытаемся получить данный файл. Однако в ответ мне приходит вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть причина? Помогите разобраться

Comment: по видимому получаете вы именно то, что запрашивали - содержимое файла. В его исходном виде. А нужно видимо отображение как в excel, табличкой. Тогда вопрос: ваш viewer точно умеет правильно парсить подобные файлы? Потому что результат очень похож на результат открытия excel-файла в блокноте.

Comment: @rdorn я забыл пояснить. То, что я получаю — это то, что приходит в браузер. То есть приходит не сам файл, а содержимое файла в ответ на POST-запрос. Если под ридером вы понимаете офисную программу, то у меня просто нет файла для открытия.

Comment: Ну правильно. А в браузере кто будет парсить содержимое файла для правильного отображения? Сам он этого не умеет.